# Jquery add attributes of child elements

Tags: jquery, loops, attributes

I have an `<ul>` list where all the children `<li>` have an "home-made" attribute of size like this:

```
<ul class="container">
    <li size="3"></li>
    <li size="5"></li>
    <li size="2"></li>
</ul>
```

How do I get the size value of all the children and then add them to, so i end up with a variable that is equal to (in this case) 10?
The number of children and the `size` number is dynamic, so I am guessing that I need some kind of loop?

Comment: Why don't you use `data-*` attribute for custom attributes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the simplest way:

```
var sum = 0;

$('.container li').each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).attr('size');
});

console.log(sum);
```

Here is a more complicated way for modern browsers:

```
var sum = $('.container li').map(function() {
    return +$(this).attr('size');
}).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Well.. Maybe because usually people use it to reduce a collection to a certain value, as in Map/Reduce algorithm. However, you may also exploit `reduce` to expand an array or transform it to an object.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
var sum = 0;

$('.container li[size]').each(function(){
  sum += +$(this).attr('size');
});

console.log(sum);
```

Note : To be frank, i just copied the summing stuff from VisioN's Answer.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.container li').each(function() {
var p = parseInt($(this).prop('size'));
sum += p;
});
alert(sum);
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Tzk4/)**

Comment: i believe you meant `sum += p;` instead of `sum += q;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $(".container>li[size]").each(function(){
        var p = parseInt($(this).attr('size'));
        sum += p;
    });
    alert(sum);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jQy6m/)